# Converting js time stamp to work in CMV application that read field values

Tags: javascript, widget, configurable-map-viewer

This might be a somewhat basic question but I cannot seem to get the logic to work. I am having a search widget search through dates to find similar records of what an asset was last serviced in the field. I noticed that when I read the raw data output from the application, it is not in a usable format.

The input from my layer is in the formatt "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" but the raw output from my application in js is a string of numbers. I want to convert this string back into a real date so the user can search for a year, such as "2012" or whatever they want.

Here is the code block I am working with...

```
           attributeSearches: [
                {
                    name: 'Search For Hydrants',
                    searchFields: [
                        {
                            name: 'Hydrant Test',
                            label: 'Year Tested',
                            expression: ('TESTDATE LIKE \'[value]%\')',

                            placeholder: 'Enter a year',
                            required: true,
                            minChars: 4
                        },
                    ],
```

Anyone know the proper way to format the expression?

Answer (score 1):

The expression you provided:

```
expression: '(TESTDATE LIKE \'[value]%\')'
```

will not work. As an example, if the user enters in `2012` for the search value, it would create a where clause of

```
(TESTDATE LIKE '2012%')
```

which will not provide any results.

First off, a "LIKE" operator cannot be used with a date field so you'd have to use comparison operators such as `=`, `>`, `<=` etc

Second, the proper format for querying dates is dependent on your database back-end. Refer to [this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000.htm) for assistance on the various date formats and query syntax for different data sources.

For that last part of the answer, I will assume you are using SQL Server and also assume you only want the user to enter in a YEAR, your expression will look something like this:

```
expression: '(TESTDATE >= \'01/01/[value]\') AND (TESTDATE <= \'12/31/[value] 11:59:59 PM\')'
```

which will create a where clause something like this:

```
(TESTDATE >= '01/01/2012') AND (TESTDATE <= '12/31/2012 11:59:59 PM')
```

To test this, you can use that where clause in the REST API Query interface to verify it gives you the results your desire.